# Can't properly process incoming request path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, url

i'm trying to implement verification on java spring and i need to set up method in Controller that will process links like this:

https://MyWebsite.io/api/v1/auth/verify/v1WKKvOWLcLeQepiZ3c0xj9tnPFlW3eOeajASdMhRx1kvhHrdBqDLFlzxE/aLIlo26hh6Q74iPVTjWvDJUVVSM8zEqMxTqBLRjbJaFH3RNnXsNpcRhJSsOSYSOAL0eE/WPiEYwdKmg5zg1VNCo1JFQ==

where v1WKKvOWLcLeQepiZ3c0xj9tnPFlW3eOeajASdMhRx1kvhHrdBqDLFlzxE/aLIlo26hh6Q74iPVTjWvDJUVVSM8zEqMxTqBLRjbJaFH3RNnXsNpcRhJSsOSYSOAL0eE/WPiEYwdKmg5zg1VNCo1JFQ== is a encrypted information about user

but i can't process this url because of the "/", can i somehow convert this url so it will correctly process in this controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {
    @GetMapping("/verify/{key}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> verify(@PathVariable String key){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(key);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change web site encryption part, why don't you use base64 for encoding before sending it as only an encrypted string?
Like below

```
https://MyWebsite.io/api/v1/auth/verify/{base64-encoded-string}
```

You can encode a string by using btoa() function which is pure Javascript. So you don't have to worry about the frontend frameworks you use.

Your backend code should look like below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {
    @GetMapping("/verify/{key}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> verify(@PathVariable String key){
        String decodedInfo = new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(key));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(decodedInfo);
    }
}
```

This code will help you avoid special characters.

Comment: Actually i used Base64.getEncoder(), so figured it out by changing to Base64.getUrlEncoder(). Thanks a lot!